# How to edit content of panels Custom text that was made reusable?

Tags: 7, panels

I'v created a Custom text element for page manager and made it reusable, and I'm not able to edit it now in Panels. Is it possible to edit such Panels elements after they were made reusable?

Thanks

Comment: I'v updated the question because I'v found how to view the content, it is very easy just click on the triangle inside the element and you will see its content.

Answer (score 2):

If you go into the panels from the structure menu... you will see "Manage custom content" on the top right.